# How to Manage Esign on cloud servers or private servers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, documentation, digital-signature

We were asked to create a web application that requests a digital signature (Esign) from several individuals, so far I have only found solutions that work through APIs from third-party supporters such as paid services.

My question is if there is something in .net that allows me to Request the signature (Esign) from an individual to sign the Document on the server and later repeat this process with all the other people, at the moment every option that I have found requires having the document locally (which has been discarded due to Home Office)

_The Esign used is applied through a reader device that requires a card with the digital signature approved by our Government, this works well with Acrobat reader and office, but requires that the file be managed locally.
_Honestly, we do not know how to proceed with this project since we are required to fully manage the information in the "cloud" or on the company's server, which makes the signature request difficult.
If a solution is known in any other language that is compatible with .net or C# it would be great.

1-Request and sign (with Esign) a document PDF type or Office platform such as Word or Excel
2-The entire process must be carried out online through a web page created in ASP.net or similar like Visula Studio code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.